# Where to ask how to prevent location-based page redirection

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have this question:

> I am trying to access the site https://www.uspoloassn.com/ but redirect me to http://la.uspoloassn.com/ (I'm from Mexico). I have tried using different browsers, deleting cookies and using a VPN as an extension of Chrome.
>
> How to prevent such redirections and see the original site that I want to access?

Which would be the right site on which to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's something that the target site is doing, so you should contact their support.

How to get a generic site to see you as being from a country different than what you are has almost certainly been answered at [Super User](https://superuser.com).